# Call a python function from one class in another

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have difficulties in the basics of functions

**a.py**

```
import b
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

class A:
  def method1():
    config = SafeConfigParser()
    b = B()
    b.method2(config)
```

**b.py**

```
class B:
  def method2(config)
    config.
    # The editor does not show the inbuilt methods of config here
```

I am using IntelliJ IDE

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @nbryans I do not get an error. But I just expect the python interpreter to show me the inbuilt methods of config. Is my understanding wrong

Comment: The editor has no way to tell what methods `config` has, especially with the syntax error in `def method1:`. Depending on your editor, it might not even do autocomplete.

Comment: What editor?  PyDev (and others) you can use `assert isinstance(config, SafeConfigParser)` which will hint to the editor what class an object represents and code completion will "work" again.

Comment: I think that op is looking for something similar to the functionality that you get in an IDE like Eclipse or something. Is that right?

Comment: Updated the question. Fixed syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is not `#include`.  It automatically namespaces everything to the imported name.  Your first example should look like this

```
import b
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

class A:
  def method1:
    config = SafeConfigParser()
    c = b.B()
    c.method2(config)
```

Notice how I had to do `b.B()` to get the `B` class, because it was namespaced to `b`, the module that was imported.

Python is not staticly-typed.  You could pass any object into `B.method2()`.  You're expecting your editor to auto-complete for the `SafeConfigParser` object because that's what you're passing to it in `A`, but that's just one instance.  Python (and your editor) has no way of knowing all the possible types of your arguments you may pass to `method2()` (unless you're using type hinting, which is a fairly new feature, and still doesn't enforce variable types, it would simply be for display purposes in your editor).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1. The hint doesn't show up because this code has typos and will not run anyway. You're missing `()` after `method1` and a colon after `method2(config)`. Also your `B` class will not be automatically visible, you should refer to it as `b.B` in your `a.py` file.
2. Your editor doesn't guess at all the possible program flows. For example you could call `method2` from some other place with a string or integer or anything else as a parameter. The editor is just guessing here, so it's just as likely to not give you any hints.

Without saying what the editor is, it's hard to say what the real reason is. Fix the code first, then look for specific answers.

If you're using python > 3.5, then you can use type hints which may help as well. (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Comment: I am using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You can something similar to what you're looking for with the `dir()` [function in python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). This will print everything that's in the scope of the variable. Just change your `b.py` file to this:

```
class B:
  def method2(config)
    print(dir(config))
```